# Do cryotherapy chambers reduce healing time and relieve pain and fatigue?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

There's a fad going around, especially in the NBA to use "Cryotherapy" to reduce healing time and relieve pain and fatigue.  The patient is placed in a chamber, which is lowered to -166 degrees Celsius (107 Kelvin), for about five minutes.  There are many reported benefits, but I haven't been able to find anything to legitimize the treatment beyond anecdotes from players, coaches, and company representatives, nor have I found any skeptical debunking.

- [Maximus Cryotherapy Chambers](http://cryotherapychamber.co.uk/en/therapy.html)
- [Fox Sports](http://www.foxsportsnorth.com/01/27/12/Wolves-get-pain-relief-at-minus-166-degr/msn_landing.html?blockID=654530)

Is cryotherapy an accepted, evidence-based, medical modality, an unproven possibility, a pipe dream, or a fraud?

Comment: I think whether this is better than an ice bath is a better question, cooling has already been shown to help in many cases.

Comment: Note that the word "cryotherapy" has long been applied o such proven techniques as icing a sprain.

Comment: The word [Cryotherapy](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/cryotherapy) (aka Cryosurgery) is primarily a medical term that refers to the process of freezing off warts, skin tags, and similar afflictions. I suggest a title edit to disambiguate. It's also loosely used to refer to any of a number of valid medical treatments that reduce body temperature locally or globally.

Comment: @Alain, is that okay now?

Comment: @Oddthinking Looks good to me :)

Comment: How the hell does being held in an environment at -166 degrees C for 5 minutes not kill you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of studies for you from Europe:

> **Objectives:** The aim of this study was to determine the influence of whole body cryostimulation on aerobic and anaerobic 
>   capacities.
>   [...]
>   **Conclusions:** It can be concluded 
>   that whole body cryostimulation can be beneficial, at least in males, for increasing anaerobic capacity in sport disciplines 
>   involving speed and strength.

—[Influence of the ten sessions of the whole body cryostimulation on aerobic and anaerobic capacity](http://www.imp.lodz.pl/upload/oficyna/artykuly/pdf/full/2010/2_Kilmek.pdf) by Andrzej T. Klimek et al.

> In all testing sessions, the simulated 48 min trail run induced a similar, significant amount of muscle damage. Maximal muscle strength and perceived sensations were recovered after the first WBC session (post 1 h), while recovery took 24 h with FIR, and was not attained through the PAS recovery modality. No differences in plasma CK activity were recorded between conditions. Three WBC sessions performed within the 48 hours after a damaging running exercise accelerate recovery from EIMD to a greater extent than FIR or PAS modalities.

—[Effects of whole-body cryotherapy vs. far-infrared vs. passive modalities on recovery from exercise-induced muscle damage in highly-trained runners](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0027749) by Christophe Hausswirth et al.

There are several other good ones showing benefits.

Comment: Acronym buster: **WBC**: Whole body cryotherapy, **FIR**: Far Infra-Red, **PAS**: Passive recovery (control), **CK**:plasma creatine kinase, **EIMD**: Exercise-induced muscle damage